# page view controller hide indicator dots and stop in the last page (can't come back)

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, swift3

I have a page control in my project and I want to do two things :
1. I want to hide indicator dots in the last page 
2. I want to lock the last page in the (page VC(my class)) that I can't come back to the first page 
here is my code

```
class pageVC : UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource , UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

lazy var VCArr : [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.VCInstance(name : "FirtsVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name : "SecondVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"ThirdVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"FourthVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"FivethVC")]
}()

private func VCInstance(name : String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    if VCArr.last != nil {
        print("first Page Reached!")
    }

    if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC] , direction: .forward , animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let pageVC = UIPageControl()

    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        }else if view is UIPageControl{
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            pageVC.numberOfPages = 5
            pageVC.center = self.view.center
            pageVC.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 180 ;
        }
    }
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex-1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return VCArr.last
    }

    guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArr[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex+1
    guard nextIndex < VCArr.count
        else {
        return VCArr.first
    }

    guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }
    return VCArr[nextIndex]
}


 public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    return VCArr.count
}

 public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first , let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }

    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (VCArr.last!.isViewLoaded)
    {
        print("It is Done!!!")
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this, which is making the page view to return to the first one when it is in the last one:

```
let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex+1
guard nextIndex < VCArr.count
    else {
    return nil //was VCArr.first
}
```

And to make it hidden, first move the `let pageVC = UIPageControl()` below the `class pageVC : UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource , UIPageViewControllerDelegate {` to make it public within the class. Then add:

```
if nextIndex == VCArr.count{
    pageVC.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: If I Delete that method that you said I will receive Error

Comment: I see. Then do not delete it, try replacing "retrn VCArr.firsr" with "retrn nil". I will edit my answer

Comment: Ok It was done but Now Just in the last page It will be Stop and In the First page you can scroll back and go to the Last Page! 
And the indicator Dots Are Still Appear!

Comment: Then, below pageVC.isHidden = true you have to set your page view scrollEnabled to false